# Date format issue in PHP year is (1300)

Tags: php

I'm converting PHP date format from `Y-m-d` to `d-m-Y`. The date is **1399-10-10** and after conversion I've got result like **01-01-1970**

Here my code is :

```
$dob = ($post['dob']!='')?date('d-m-Y',strtotime($post['dob'])):'';
```

But result is: **01-01-1970**

I need this result: **10-10-1399**

Can anyone guide me to resolve this issue?

Comment: $post is incorrect assumed $_POST['dob']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit, the below seems to work as Jeroen stated if you are running a 64bit version of PHP, below in the comments you will find a working copy on the sandbox site.

Check the contents of `$post['dob']` is it `$post` and not `$_POST`

I ran this,

```
$date = '1399-10-10';
echo date( 'd-m-Y', strtotime( $date ) );
```

And got this,

```
10-10-1399
```

More than likely the variable going in is not correct.

---

A second option is to use the following,

```
$date = new DateTime( '1399-10-10' );
echo $date->format( 'd-m-Y' );
```

This is of course assuming that the `$post` is `$post` and not `$_POST` and that the content of the variable is correct.

Comment: Also you have errors try this = `$post[ 'dob' ] = '1399-10-10';
$dob = ( $post[ 'dob' ] != '' ? date( 'd-m-Y', strtotime( $post[ 'dob' ] ) ) : '' );
echo $dob;`

Comment: WTH are the negative votes for??  Have you tried that code yourselves?  It runs in both 5.6 and 7.0 with no issues.

Comment: @jeroen http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3a354cf6e692535f6392a2eab96a611783b19038

Comment: @jeroen Done, from here on I will use the eval.in site as the one I am using seems to cause issues.  I have also supplied a second option for the date conversion as well as an explanation that the `$post` may not be correct.  However, without further information from the OP we will not know if the `$post` is indeed correct.

Comment: Thanks you reply jeroen also am using second one it was working fine .